# how do I get HTML inputs in $_POST for a file upload

Tags: html, forms, enctype

With the following code in an HTML file, I am able to read in the file but I am not getting the name of the fileToUpload through in the POST. If I remove the ENCTYPE, I do get the fileToUpload through, the problem is that I believe that multipart/form-data is mandatory for a file upload and I I don't use that encopding method, the rest of my routine to process the file goes round in loops.

If there a way to get the name of the user=-selected file through using multipart/form-data?

PS, foo.php has the following code to check the contents of the POST:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The output with the below HTML code is "Array()", without the ENCTYPE, the output is Array ( [fileToUpload] => energydata2_X.CSV ), the latter is what I need. Thanks for any guidance!

```
<form action="foo.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

  Select CSV file to upload:
  
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File"/>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_FILES` to access the uploaded files.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to use PHP but I can access environment variables if I know their names. Is there a comprehensive list of POST variable names passed with a FORM in HTML? I use dBase and it has a getEnv() function that return OS environment variables. getEnv("REQUEST_METHOD") returns "POST", but getEnv("$_FILES") or getEnv("_FILES") returns an empty string, i.e. the variable doesn't exist with that name in the OS.

Comment: I found something here that matches what I can access in my built-in stuff: http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html. It doesn't look like FILES is part of that list. Meanwhile I found that the file name is part of the multipart/form-data, so I can extract the file name from there. It's just a shame I can only access that info after the upload has completed...